# How to pass function as paramater to AsynTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

since im new in android development, and i need to provide an asynctask class for my http request. i have a lot of http request function type in one activity, and i want to make it dynamic. so i wanted to create only one AsyncTask function that can run all my function.

so this is the example

```
  private class WebServiceCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        pBar.setClickable(false);
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // a function that i passed
       Function01();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try{
         some code
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        pBar.setClickable(true);
        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

and i just call like this

```
Oncreate(
new WebServiceCall().execute(function01());
```

)

any help and code sample would be appreciate,
thanks

Comment: Better add a constructor that takes the callback. Then you can instantiate and call it like new WebServiceCall(function01).execute();

Comment: can show the code sample?

Comment: Google for how to implement a callback. But i wonder why you want this. If the asynctask is a private class in an activity then you can just call every function defined in that activity. So what is your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by a `function` as a parameter to another function!

but you can use `Interfaces` for this purpose.

for example:

create an Call Back interface that can be called in `onPostExecute()`

```
public interface ResponseCallback {

    void onRespond();
}
```

and before calling asynckTask define it like this:

```
   ResponseCallback callback = new ResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onRespond() {
              //code to be done after calling it from onPostExecute
            }
        };
```

and pass `callback` to the `constructor` of of the `asynckTask` and call it in `onPostExecute`

---

of course you can modify the signature of the `interface` to what ever you want.

Comment: i want to called in DoInbackground , because its a heavy process. could it be ?

Comment: the methods in an interface can be called anywhere [of course if the interface variable is not null] but it's all about your code logic! me myself never had to call a callback in `doInBackground`!

Answer (score 0):

Send class object with your function and call function from object in AsyncTask.

```
public class A
{
//your function
int function()
{
return...;
}
}

private class WebServiceCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    A myobj;
    WebServiceCall(A mycustomslass)
    {
         myobj = mycustomclass;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        pBar.setClickable(false);
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // a function that i passed

        int cur = myobj.function();//this your function
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try{
         some code
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        pBar.setClickable(true);
        pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

and you can call like

```
Oncreate(
new WebServiceCall(new A()).execute();
)
```

Comment: can you show the code sample ? or simplly modified my code?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your question directly, but I urge you to investigate both the fairly-well advertised problems with using AsyncTask for anything that's likely to take more than a few milliseconds, and the several really good HTTP / REST frameworks for Android, e.g. Retrofit.