# Return onPostExecute Value into onBindViewHolder of RecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I have chat screen where i am downloading attachment from FirebaeStorage.
I have various formats of file which can be send doc,pdf,apk etc. and for each i have same TextViews and ImageViews.

In Chat screen's recyclerview adapter i am setting file path of local storage which can be obtain by run AsyncTask which downloads files from Firebase Storage and return file path.This work perfectly but the issue is how to get back that file path in onBindViewHolder on particular if else

Here is my RecyclerAdapter where i am calling AsyncTask and need result back into same scope and **wait till download completes then set views according to data returned**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final Chat_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {


if (fileType.equals("pdf")){
 new DownloadFileFromFS(Download_URL,FileName+".pdf").execute();

//HERE I NEED THE RESULT FROM ASYNCTASK AND WAIT TILL DOWNLOAD COMPLETES
 //THEN SET THE VIEWS WITH RETURN RESULT FROM ASYNCTASK

    if (DownloadFilePath!=null){
        File file=new File(DownloadFilePath);
        long sizeFile=file.length()/1024; //In KB
        holder.Doc_FileName.setText(DownloadFilePath);
        holder.Doc_FileSize.setText(String.valueOf(sizeFile));
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG,"DOWNLOAD FILE PATH IS NULL");
    }

}
```

AsyncTask

```
public class DownloadAttachment extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    String DownloadUrl,fileName;
    File file;
    Context context;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public static final String TAG="###Download Attachment";

    public DownloadAttachment(Context context, String downloadUrl, String fileName) {
        DownloadUrl = downloadUrl;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.context=context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int count;
        try {
            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            Log.d(TAG,"DO IN BACKGROUND RUNNING");
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Downloaded Files/");
            if (dir.exists() == false) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }


            URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl); //you can write here any link
            file = new File(dir, fileName);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d(TAG, "download begining");
            Log.d(TAG, "download url:" + url);
            Log.d(TAG, "downloaded file name:" + fileName);

       /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            //this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
            int lengthOfFile=ucon.getContentLength();
       /*
        * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
        */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

       /*
        * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
        */
            ByteArrayOutputStream baf = new ByteArrayOutputStream(5000);
            int current = 0;
            long total=0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.write((byte) current);
                total=total+current;
                //PUBLISH THE PROGRESS
                //AFTER THIS onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)(total*100)/lengthOfFile);
            }


       /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            Log.d("DownloadManager", "download ready in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");
            Log.d(TAG,"File Path "+file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
        }

        return file.toString();
    }    

}
```

**UPDATE** As @Atef Hares suggest,i did implement in code.its working fine but what if i have different format. How to call particular if else after getting result from asynctask cuz code suggested only call pdf if statement.

```
if (fileType.equals("pdf")){
    final String nameFile=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    new DownloadFileFromFS(chat_wrapper.getDocuments(),nameFile).execute();

     filePathInterface=new FilePath() {
        @Override
        public void LocalFilePath(final String Path) {
           //HERE I AM GETTING RESULT FROM ASYNCTASK
           //AND SETTING VIEWS ACCORDING TO IT            
        }
    };


}
else if (fileType.equals("doc")){
//HOW TO GET RESULT FROM ASYNCTASK HERE IF FILETYPE IS "doc"

}
else if (fileType.equals("ppt")){
//HOW TO GET RESULT FROM ASYNCTASK HERE IF FILETYPE IS "ppt"
}
```

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42656227/5993410)

Comment: @AtefHares I use interface to get result back to activity but issue comes i have to wait until download completes and then set views with data and without waiting it returns null

Comment: Why your are calling Asynctask from adapter?! You should not use the adapter unless you have the data that will be displayed, moreover, don't call asynctask from the adapter, call it from the activity/fragment and get required data then pass it to the adapter to display it

Comment: cuz i want file path back to adapter not in activity the reason is i need to download different file format and its easy to detect on adapter then activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay using interfaces -as you know- will achieve what you need!

just do it like this:

```
public interface AsyncTaskCallback {
    void onSuccess (String filePath);
}
```

and in the Adapter, don't set any data to the view unless you got the data back from asyncTask, like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final Chat_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

         //Initialize filetype here

        new DownloadFileFromFS(Download_URL, FileName + "."+ filetype, new AsyncTaskCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String filePath) {
                //HERE I NEED THE RESULT FROM ASYNCTASK AND WAIT TILL DOWNLOAD COMPLETES
                //THEN SET THE VIEWS WITH RETURN RESULT FROM ASYNCTASK

                if (filePath != null) {
                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    long sizeFile = file.length() / 1024; //In KB
                    holder.Doc_FileName.setText(filePath);
                    holder.Doc_FileSize.setText(String.valueOf(sizeFile));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DOWNLOAD FILE PATH IS NULL");
                }
            }
        }).execute();
    }
```

Comment: This approach is right i think but what if i have multiple formats like Doc,Docx etc. Do i need to create different interface or different asynctask for each format of file

Comment: @Ritu what do mean by creating different interface & asynctask?

Comment: In each if else i am checking file extension like above and if file is PDF thn doing task according file format.But the issue is like you called this interface inside `if (fileType.equals("pdf"))` it will only work for `pdf` but what can i do in other `else if (fileType.equals("doc"))` or `else if (fileType.equals("ppt"))` etc. that's why i asked do i need to create different interface for each format  or different asynctask

Comment: @Ritu No, of course not, Just first modify your asyncTask class to work for all types (if it is not already, but I think it is) Also modify the interface (if u needed to) to handle all success case of all types. then in the adapter, first check for the type and save it to some variable, then call the asynckTask on this variable(type) and in the callback interface do ur work (initialize the views) ---- So the asynckTask call will be after the `if else` block.

Comment: @Ritu I did not understands your update, how the defined interface will be called from asynctask while you did not even sent it to the Asynctask!. Anyway, if your original code logic is to check for file type then just call the asynctask and set the view on callback, then you don't even need to use `if else`, check my edit

Comment: if i call asynctask for in pdf if else then it will return back with result to its interface inside if condition of `filetype==pdf`. So what if i am calling from `else if (fileType.equals("doc")` then result will be back to inside `if (fileType.equals("pdf")`cuz there is an interface which has result from asynctask

Comment: Thx the way you suggest to declare every interface locally i did same and its working. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @Ritu Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback.

```
public interface FileDownloadCallback {
    void onSuccess (String filePath);
    void onFailed ();

}
```

Pass that in to your AsyncTask and call it from onPostExecute.

Comment: i do use interface but issue that it will return null cuz file is not downloaded so i have to wait till download complete then execute code after calling `AsyncTask`

Comment: @Ritu Thats why onPostExecute exists, after completing long running task in doInBackground

Comment: Okay, say you pass in a FileDownloadCallback to your AsyncTask and assign it to a variable named mCallback. In onPostExecute (), you take the String that was returned from doInBackground ()  (onPostExecute (String s)) and call the mCallback.onSuccess() method and pass the String as a parameter.  Now in your view holder, from within the onSuccess () callback, set your TextViews and do whatever else you need to do. It's guaranteed that onSuccess () in your viewholder won't be called until the AsyncTask is done executing.

Comment: What if i have something like that `else if (valueofDocuments){

if (FileType.getDocuments().contains("pdf")){
//Run AsyncTask and set Result to text view
}
}`